# Objective c didSelectRowIndexPath - Passing data to other View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Hi there i am trying to pass the data from my TableViewController_My_boards to ViewController_Update_Boards but i am not sure how to do it
So first of all i create a dictionary with the data from firestore

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    _db = [FIRFirestore firestore];
    
    objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:5];
    [[self.db collectionWithPath:@"boards"]
        getDocumentsWithCompletion:^(FIRQuerySnapshot * _Nullable snapshot,
                                     NSError * _Nullable error) {
          if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error getting documents: %@", error);
          } else {
            for (FIRDocumentSnapshot *document in snapshot.documents) {
                NSString *key = document.documentID;
                NSDictionary *boardDetails = document.data;
                [self->objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards setObject:boardDetails forKey:key];
                
                //NSLog(@"%@ => %@", document.documentID, document.data);

            }
              NSLog(@"self->objNSDictionaryListOfBoards= %@", self->objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards);
              [self.tableView reloadData];

          }
        }];}
```

After that i display the name of each item in my table view cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleIdentifier1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   
   // Configure the cell...
   NSString *boardNo =[objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards allKeys][indexPath.row];
   NSString *boardName =objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards [boardNo][@"name"];

   cell.textLabel.text=boardName;
   return cell;
}
```

And then i want to pass the data to next viewcontroller when i click on the cell with the didSelectRowIndexPath
This is what i have but im lost from here.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_Update_Boards"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    //[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:TRUE];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `UIViewController *vc=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_Update_Boards"];`, here `vc`, you know its class right? So cast it: `MyViewController *vc = (MyViewController *)[sb instatiante...];` You have the `indexPath` in that method, you know how to retrieve the `boardNo` and then `vc.boardNo = boardNo`, or any other property you want. Now, `[objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards allKeys]`, here the order isn't guaranteed. You should use a NSArray instead of a NSDictionary for you datasource.

Comment: thanks for answering so quick. Im not understanding how should i do, im pretty new to objective c. Im not sure how to retrieve the boardNo

Comment: @Juan : the same way you do in cellForRow

Comment: @Ptit Xav thanks i am trying like this but i get Property 'boardName' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'. - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_Update_Boards"];
    NSString *boardNo =[objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards allKeys][indexPath.row];
    NSString *boardName =objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards [boardNo][@"name"];
    vc.boardName=boardName;

Comment: You need to cast the vac return from storyboard to the correct view controller class (the one you have defined with the needed interface)

Comment: I dont understand you but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Custom Class for the view controller in your Storyboard has been set to `ViewController_Update_Boards`, and you have a header file for that controller that looks similar to this:

```
@interface ViewController_Update_Boards: UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *boardName;

@end
```

Make sure your `TableViewController_My_boards` class has this at the top:

```
#import "ViewController_Update_Boards"
```

then change your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController_Update_Boards *vc = (ViewController_Update_Boards *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_Update_Boards"];
    NSString *boardNo =[objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards allKeys][indexPath.row];
    vc.boardName = objNSDictinoaryListOfBoards[boardNo][@"name"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:TRUE];

}
```

Comment: Following the steps is now working perfect. Great explanation, i have understood perfect i appreciate it.